# Best Practice of Inheritance: Property should be an interface too or not?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 2 interfaces and 2 classes:

```
public interface interface A
{
     List<B> MyList { get; set; }
}

public interface interface B
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ImplementA : A
{
     List<ImplementB> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class ImplementB : B
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So this gives me an error because ImplementA doesn't fullfill the Interface A. It doesn't because I would have to have the property List of interface B instead of List of ImplementB.

What is the best practice to fullfill the Interface but still be able to have a concrete classe within classes AND a abstract interface in the interface?

Comment: `public class ImplementA`?

Comment: yeah fixed it sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is very friendly to make it [Generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-interfaces).

```csharp
public interface A<T>
{
     List<T> MyList { get; set; }
}

public interface B
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ImplementA : A<ImplementB>
{
    public List<ImplementB> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class ImplementB : B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or this one, upon your needs

```csharp
public class ImplementA : A<B>
{
    public List<B> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, where is InterfaceB now used?